# How to change style of an element onClick at another element REACT?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to change .page-header when i click on standard-basic. I tried to do this:

```
#standard-basic:focus ~ .page-header{
  display: none;
}
```

But it can't help me. How can change style of page-header in react or maybe just in js? I use functional component

```
 <span id="pageHeader" className="page-header">TechPrice</span>
  <form
    className={props.classes.root}
    noValidate
    autoComplete="off"
    className="search-form"
  >
    <TextField className="textField" id="standard-basic" label="Поиск" />
    <SearchIcon className="search-icon" />
  </form>
```

Comment: Add a local state to select styles for your element.

Comment: You cannot target parents or their siblings with CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use style object and set display prop to none depend on some state

Example:

```
<span id="pageHeader" style={{"display": `isVisible ? "block" : "none"`}}>TechPrice</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is no parent selector** in `CSS/CSS3`.

Please read this topic: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

To achieve your goal you have to use `JavaScript/React/any other framework/library`

Comment: Look at the question and it's tags, he is using React. This is not an answer to the question.